# How to calculate average using vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm actually trying to create a program to calculate the average of the numbers added in a vector.

Firstly I declared and initialize two doubles called, grades and value:

```
double grades = 0.0; // Number of grades to work with
double value = 0.0; // Each value submitted in the push_back(value);
```

Once I do that, I declare the vector and ask for the user the quantity of grades to average, lets say 6, maybe?

```
// Declare and initialize a <vector> of doubles called gradesVector
vector<double> gradesVector;   // initially the vector is empty
cout << "How many grades would you like to work with?:" << endl;
cin >> grades;
```

Then I pass those values into a function called `passVectors`

```
passVectors(grades, value, gradesVector);
```

The pass vector looks like this:

```
void passVectors(double grades, double value, vector<double> &gradesVector) {
  for(int i = 0; i < grades; i++){
    value = validateDouble(value);
    gradesVector.push_back(value);
  }
}
```

Now, that's where my problem resides, I would like to implement a way to calculate the average but for that I need to return something from the function, am I right?. Void functions do not return anything so I'm having a lot of troubles with it. I tried doing this but it did not work as it only returned 0(zero)

```
double average = value / grades;
cout << average;
```

Can anyone guide me through this?

NOTE: I'm trying to only create functions. Right now I just want to have it working but after that, I will probably create a function that takes two parameters, one of them is going to be values and the second one is going to be grades.

Am I approaching this in the right way?

Comment: "I need to return something from the function, am I right?" I don't think you are right. The `passVectors` function takes a reference to `vector`, so the data can be taken out via the reference.

Comment: use  `std::accumulate`

Comment: You'd better use an integral type to store the number of grades. Something like `std::size_t`, not `double`.

Comment: Do you want to get `gradesVector` as a return value from `passVectors()` function?